# Backbone events being fired without trigger

Tags: coffeescript, backbone-events

So I have a strange issue where my backbone events are getting fired even though they haven't been triggered yet. Essentially I'm making a note editor application. In the note itself, a user can press cmd + b to bold text, or any of the other normals. That then triggers an event which bubbles up to the AppController which should be subscribed to that event and call the correct method.

Here is the view for the note where the trigger is called:

```
class MeetingNote.View.NoteView extends Backbone.View
    adminTemplate: _.template($('#AdminNoteTemplate').html())
    normalTemplate: _.template($('#NormalNoteTemplate').html())
    className: 'note' 
    events: 
            'keydown'                       : 'handleKeyDownsForStyling'

    # all of the normal backbone stuff.... init/render/blah

    handleKeyDownsForStyling: (e) ->
            if @admin == true 
                      if e.metaKey  
                            switch e.which 
                                  when 66 then @trigger "boldSelection" 
                                  when 73 then @trigger "italicizeSelection"
                                  when 85 then @trigger "underlineSelection"
```

Then here is my AppController which binds to the event when the NoteView is instantiated

```
class MeetingNote.View.AppController extends Backbone.View
    template: _.template($('#MeetingNoteAppTemplate').html()) 
    className: 'MeetingNoteApp' 
    initialize: (options) -> 
            @admin = options.privilege                                                  
            @render()
    render: ->
            @$el.html(@template())
            $('#container').append(@$el)
            @initializeApp()

    initializeApp: ->                                       
            @adminTools = new MeetingNote.View.AdminTools if @admin == true
            notes = new MeetingNote.Collection.NotesCollection()
            notes.fetch { 
                    success: (collection) =>
                            _.each collection.models, (model) => 
                                  note = new MeetingNote.View.NoteView {model: model, privilege: @admin} 
                                  @bindNoteEvents note if @admin == true
            }

    bindNoteEvents: (note) ->
           note.on "boldSelection", @adminTools.boldSelection(), note
           note.on "italicizeSelection", @adminTools.italicizeSelection(), note
           note.on "underlineSelection", @adminTools.underlineSelection(), note
```

lastly, here is the @adminTools.boldSelection() function

```
    boldSelection: ->
            console.log( "yo" )
```

for some reason, upon page load, that console.log is being fired even though I never sent the trigger by pressing cmd + b in the note View. Anyone have any idea why a Backbone.Event would fire automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function call:

```
@adminTools.boldSelection()
#------------------------^^
```

This is a reference to a function:

```
@adminTools.boldSelection
```

You're supposed to hand [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) a reference to a function so that it can call the function later. Your `bindNoteEvents` should look more like this:

```
bindNoteEvents: (note) ->
       note.on "boldSelection",      @adminTools.boldSelection,      note
       note.on "italicizeSelection", @adminTools.italicizeSelection, note
       note.on "underlineSelection", @adminTools.underlineSelection, note
       # No parentheses here --------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```